# TFS 2018 to 2019 upgrade failed on missing Release Id

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Using a few months old database copy of our production instrance running on TFS 2018.3 i tried to upgrade it to 2019.1.
During the upgrade of the collections, one of the collections failed on step 729.

Before i go back on load a fresh database, i would like to understand the error message and make sure we prevent it in the future.

Has anyone seen this error before and know how to fix it in my upgrade ? as well as make sure this does not happen for a future upgrade ?

> [15:02:03.047] +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
>   [15:02:03.047] ++ Executing - Operation: DistributedTaskOrchestrationToDev17M141Collection, Group: DistributedTaskOrchestrationToDev17M141Collection
>   [15:02:03.047] +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
>   [15:02:03.047] Executing step: Start Queued Plans in PlanQueue
>   [15:02:03.047]   Executing step: 'Start Queued Plans in PlanQueue' DistributedTaskOrchestration.StartThrottledPlans (729 of 858)
>   [15:02:03.313]   [Error] VS402939: Release with ID 625 does not exist. Specify a valid ID and try again.
>   [15:02:03.327]   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ReleaseManagement.WebApi.Exceptions.ReleaseNotFoundException: VS402939: Release with ID 625 does not exist. Specify a valid ID and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We reported this same issue on the Microsoft Developer Community.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/720729/upgrade-to-tfs-20191-failed-with-error-vs402939.html

In our scenario, we created a production copy around May 2019 using TFS 2018.3, left it running until now and tried to upgrade this production copy into a TFS 2019.1. This failed.

It seems this issue was caused by our "outdated" production copy we left running which we later tried to upgrade to TFS 2019.

The upgrade failed because Releases have been in the queue for longer than 30 days, which caused parts to be deleted by the retention policy.

> For production environment, its advisable to cancel any stuck
>   deployments before upgrade.

I will keep this in mind, but it would be good for Microsoft to make sure the upgrade process does not fail in case there is a stuck deployment somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error info

> Executing step: 'Start Queued Plans in PlanQueue'
>   ......
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ReleaseManagement.WebApi.Exceptions.ReleaseNotFoundException:
>   VS402939: Release with ID xxx does not exist. Specify a valid ID and try again.......

It may caused by a release stuck processing in the pipeline queues.

There are few scenarios:

- Requests are busy in the pipeline queue a Pipelines.They do not have
  a 1:1 relationship with the agents. Looks like there are more
  releases with environments in progress than the available licenses.
- Clearing out requests that are in the queue: To clear out invalid
  requests, the most recommended way is to cancel any in progress
  deployments. Refer to
  https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/view-manage-releases#release-summary
- Simply refresh the release using the refresh button and try again
  which may also do the trick

Before you do the fresh database upgrade, kindly check if there are some releases hang in the queue for your collections. Check Pipelines--Agent Pools--Running Jobs. This may avoid the same issue which does not happen for a future upgrade.

Comment: Thank you, i will check that in the production environment. Any idea if i can get the test environment working ? or is getting a newer DB copy the only option ?
Our collection is almost 1TB in size so takes some effort to move around.

Comment: @Nico Afraid not, since this issue cause the upgrade process get stuck. As you say you should go back on load a fresh database, also check that specific Release not hang up in the queue of the collection. Then finally upgrade the process again. If the Release issue could not be figured out, you may have to [create an incident](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/devops/) from Microsoft to dig into database.

Comment: Hi @Patrick Your solution did not help, i could not check for stuck deployments as i only had access to the database. With the help of the Microsoft Support team we identified the cause of the issue, but did not fix it. We decided to load a fresh database copy and try the upgrade again, this time it succeeded. The cause of the issue was that we had queued deployments in our test env with no available agents, these were auto-deleted by TFS and apparently the upgrade wizard failed on this scenario. So before upgrading, check for pending deployments

Comment: @Nico Thanks for your valuable inputs and detail explanation. Especially for the root cause of issue `The upgrade failed because Releases have been in the queue for longer than 30 days, which caused parts to be deleted by the retention policy.` It will definitely help others if they got same issue here.